# Nested async functions

Tags: javascript, callback, async.js

With the following code, can I be sure that the last callback will return the updated variables?

```
var a = 0;
async.forEach(collectionarray, function(item, cb1) {
    async.forEach(collection.anotherarray, function(item, cb2) {
        a += item.number;
        cb2();
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
    })
    cb1();
}, function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(a); // will this be updated for all the collection.anotherarray.number ?
})
```

Comment: You are supposed to pass `cb1` into the inner `forEach` as the callback, not to call it immediately!

Comment: @Bergi you mean call it inside the final callback on the inner async?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of `.forEach` serves a dual purpose: as a callback when all iterations are done, or to report an error. Call `cb1()` inside that callback on the inner `.forEach`:

```
var a = 0;
async.forEach(collectionarray, function(item, cb1) {
    async.forEach(collection.anotherarray, function(item, cb2) {
        a += item.number;
        cb2();
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        cb1();
    });
}, function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(a);
})
```

The approach you've written will almost definitely not work correctly. The outer `.forEach` will assume it's done far too soon.